# Rails Nested Resources with path set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I order my resources like below, /websitename works but /username doesn't.

```
resources :websites, :path => '', :only => [:create, :show] do
    resources :pages, :only => [:create, :show, :edit]
end

resources :users, :path => '', :only => [:create, :show, :index]
```

When I reverse the order like below, /username works but /websitename doesn't.

```
resources :users, :path => '', :only => [:create, :show, :index]

resources :websites, :path => '', :only => [:create, :show] do
    resources :pages, :only => [:create, :show, :edit]
end
```

It's like one is cancelling the other out or something. Is there some way around this? Some way to encapsulate them or something? I've no idea what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one top level resource with no `:path` in practice.  It will always match so nothing after will.

With command line - you can look at `rake routes` to see the actual url patterns each route is expecting and the precedence order.

And this makes sense, right?  You wouldn't know if `/georgia` was a person or a place.

If your website routes have something special about them (like they all start with 'site') then you could do something like this.

resources :websites, :path => '', constraints: { id: /site+/ }

Put the more restrictive routes first in the routes file.

Comment: Hmmm...I see, makes sense I guess yeah. I guess I gotta think now which I want to be TL and which to hide behind the controller name :/